# Error inserting to database

Tags: android, sql, eclipse

I have a basic database that calls on string into the database(well supposed to). Whenever I click the button to save the string into the data base I get an error in my log cat saying it did not write to the data base. the application keeps going but no info shows inside the database.

**LOGCAT**

```
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828): 0.0
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828): 0.0
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1435)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at http.www.hotapp.com.timeandlocation.db.Database.createEntryLat(Database.java:76)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at http.www.hotapp.com.timeandlocation.TimeAndLocationActivity.onClick(TimeAndLocationActivity.java:131)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ENTRY METHOD**

```
public long createEntryLat(String slat) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_LATITUDE, slat);
    return ourdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

**LINE 73**

```
    return ourdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

**ONCLICK METHOUD**

```
case R.id.button001:

    lat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
     String slat = lat.getText().toString();
        //String slon = lon.getText().toString();

        Database entries = new Database (this);
        entries.open();

        entries.createEntryLat(slat);
        entries.close();

        break;
```

**LINE 131**

```
Database entries = new Database (this);
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and would love any help thanks.

Comment: How is your table defined? In particular -- what constraints does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall my application then re-install it for my changes to take action.

Answer (score 4):

The topmost line in the stack says:

```
12-02 16:39:03.551: E/Database(20828): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

Is there a constraint you are violating:

- The varchar column is unique and you are trying to insert the same value again.
- Some other constraint like primary key, foreign keys etc

Can you post the create sql for the table in question?